# Meteor redis-oplog with accounts-meld error

Tags: meteor, redis

So I just added redis-oplog to my project

https://github.com/cult-of-coders/redis-oplog

```
meteor add cultofcoders:redis-oplog
meteor add disable-oplog
```

With its default settings

And I get this error

```
W20180226-10:52:11.373(4)? (STDERR) Error: use "new" to construct a Mongo.Collection
W20180226-10:52:11.374(4)? (STDERR)     at new Mongo.Collection (packages/mongo/collection.js:30:11)
W20180226-10:52:11.374(4)? (STDERR)     at packages/splendido_accounts-meld.js:116:15
W20180226-10:52:11.374(4)? (STDERR)     at packages/splendido_accounts-meld.js:702:4
W20180226-10:52:11.374(4)? (STDERR)     at packages/splendido_accounts-meld.js:751:4
W20180226-10:52:11.374(4)? (STDERR)     at packages/splendido_accounts-meld.js:764:3
W20180226-10:52:11.374(4)? (STDERR)     at infos.forEach.info (/Users/hayksafaryan/projects/b2c/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:414:13)
W20180226-10:52:11.374(4)? (STDERR)     at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
W20180226-10:52:11.375(4)? (STDERR)     at /Users/hayksafaryan/projects/b2c/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:413:9
W20180226-10:52:11.375(4)? (STDERR)     at /Users/hayksafaryan/projects/b2c/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:463:5
W20180226-10:52:11.375(4)? (STDERR)     at Function.run (/Users/hayksafaryan/projects/b2c/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/profile.js:510:12)
=> Exited with code: 1
```

There seems to be some conflicts with this package

https://github.com/splendido/meteor-accounts-meld

Did anybody encounter this before?

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you haven't fixed this yet, did you edit **.meteor/packages** and move **cultofcoders:redis-oplog** to the top? Redis-oplog needs to be loaded before anything else that uses collections.